# What is this graph theory measurement called?

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading a scientific paper that measures the "relatedness" $s_{AB}$ of two (not necessarily connected) subgraphs of a connected graph with the formula

$$
s_{AB} = d_{AB} - \dfrac{d_{AA} + d_{BB}}{2}.
$$

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgraphs of a connected graph $G$.

Let $d_{AB}$ be the average of the distances from each node in $A$ or $B$ to the nearest node in the other subgraph. So, if a node is in both $A$ and $B$ then that distance will be $0$.

Let $d_{AA}$ be the average of the distances from each node in $A$ to the nearest node in $A$ that is not itself.

Note that all distances refer to within $G$, even if we are only looking at the nodes in one of the subgraphs.

In essence, the relatedness measure $s_{AB}$ compares the closeness of the two subgraphs (the first term) to the average closeness of the individual subgraphs (the second term). A smaller, more negative $s_{AB}$ value means the two subgraphs are close/related.

Does anyone recognize any part of this formula (or the whole thing) as an established metric in graph theory? I doubt the whole thing is original.